# return a new string where "not " has been added to the front. However, if the string already begins with "not", return the string unchanged

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function

Given a string, return a new string where "not " has been added to the front. However, if the string already begins with "not", return the string unchanged.

Examples:

```
not_string('candy') → 'not candy'
not_string('x') → 'not x'
not_string('not bad') → 'not bad'
```

Comment: So? What is the question?

Comment: In the future, I'd start with a more concise question title and then use the body for more description/detail.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return when the string already begins with "not". If the string begins without "not" then append "not " first and return.

The answer is here: https://gist.github.com/farjanul-nayem/d0eafb2f3e789ff72ff73eafe9a56926

Answer (score 0):

```
def not _string(str):
  if le n (str) >= 3 and str [:3] == "not":
    return str
  return "not " + str
  # s t r [:3] goes from the start of the string up to but not
   including index 3
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?